# Dynamic memory allocation - realloc(): invalid next size

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, realloc

My requirement is to have a dynamic memory allocation for the `char *` variable I am creatigng so that when the `while` loop in my applciation reads data, the memory allocation should increase accordinly, But what happens when I run the code is i get the erroe,

`*** glibc detected *** ./rpp: realloc(): invalid next size: 0x0000000001376010 ***`

I found many questions posted on this topic here in stackoverflow through this google search (https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=realloc%28%29%3A+invalid+next+size%3A+0x0000000002401010+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#channel=fs&q=realloc%28%29:+invalid+next+size:+) but non helped. I would really appreaciate if you experts would help me on this one to fix this error as I am now clueless on how to fix this. Following id the function which gives me the error.

```
int execScanNetowrk(){

    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char path[1035];
    char *pathFull;
    pathFull = (char*)malloc(sizeof(path));


    /* Open the command for reading. */
    fp = popen("nmap -sP -oG - 192.168.1.0/24", "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
            printf("Failed to run command\n" );
            exit;
    }

    /* Read the output a line at a time - output it. path stores each line of data per iteration*/
    while (fgets(path, sizeof(path)-1, fp) != NULL) {

        pathFull = (char*)realloc(pathFull, sizeof(path));//increase memory allocation
        strcat(pathFull,path);//concatenate char * with the read data           

    }

    printf("%s\n", a);  
    /* close */
    pclose(fp);
    free(a);
    return 0;

}
```

Thank you very much :)

Comment: Initialize `pathFull` to `NULL`. `sizeof(path)` to `realloc` is probably not working as you expect.

Comment: my bad... I see you do initialize `pathFull`.

Comment: @noloader yes that I have initialized to the size of `path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *general* technique for fixing this kind of problem is to apply [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org) which will give you more detailed error messages pointing right at the problem.

Your specific problem is here:

```
    pathFull = (char*)realloc(pathFull, sizeof(path));//increase memory allocation
```

The second argument to `realloc` is *the total number of bytes you want*, **not** the number of bytes by which to increase the allocation.  You need to track the current size of `pathFull` and do `realloc(pathFull, oldSize + sizeof(path))` or similar.

Do you really want to read the *entire* nmap output into memory before processing it at all, or is your actual goal to read entire *lines* into memory before processing them?  Your code is trying to do the former, but you probably meant to do the latter, in which case [`getline`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) may be easier to use than mucking about with `fgets`.

Obligatory nitpick: when coding in C *do not* cast the return value of `malloc` nor `realloc`.  It is unnecessary and may prevent the compiler from noticing when you forget to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: thank you very much for the descriptive answer i will try the suggestions you made and post back. and yes I was trying to get the data and then process..but processing while on the loop seems better now :)